# how to tail the penult occurence of a pattern in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I know that using  `tail -1` I can take the last of occurence of a specific pattern in  a file. But how to tail the penult? I tried `tail-2` which gave me the penult and the last.

I am using bash

thanks

Comment: please consider illustrating your need with sample input and required output. just numbers 1-10, each on a spparate line and then required output from that input will make it much easier to be sure we're giving you the correct advice. Use the 'code block' feature of the editor by highlighting your samples, and then clicking the {} at the top of the edit box. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain head/tail:

```
tail -3|head -2
```

which, assuming you've got a file like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

will have tail produce

```
c
d
e
```

and then head grabs

```
c
d
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 'x;$p' inputfile
```

This swaps the current line into hold space and the previous line into pattern space. On the last line, the contents of pattern space is printed (which happens to be the penultimate line.